# Google maps lat long array

Tags: php, google-maps

I have two arrays `$lat`, `$long`,

```
1   "73.0785729"
2   "73.0785729"
3   "73.0785729"
```

and same for the `$long`.

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', init);

```
function init() {
    var mapOptions = {
        zoom: 11,
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(40.6700, -73.9400),
        styles: []
    };
    var mapElement = document.getElementById('map');
    var map = new google.maps.Map(mapElement, mapOptions);
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: new google.maps.LatLng({{$lat}}, {{$long}}),
        map: map,
        title: 'Snazzy!'
    });
}
```

It throws `htmlspecialchars() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given`.

Comment: Iterate over your array and create a marker for each lat-long pair.

Comment: iterate on `var marker` ? Please answer the question.

Comment: he's saying for each coordinate. create a marker. that is, instantiate a Map object

Comment: before you do this you have to make sure that the php array is converted to a javascript array. use json_encode for this.

Comment: Still not working

Answer (score 1):

You have to pass your PHP datas to Javascript with [json_encode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) :

```
<?php

//Construct the array you want, assuming $lat and $long have the same length
$markers = array();
foreach($lat as $i => $currentLat) {
    $markers[] = array("lat" => $currentLat, "long" => $long[$i]);
}
```

And modify you Javascript :

```
function init() {
    var mapOptions = {
        zoom: 11,
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(40.6700, -73.9400),
        styles: []
    };
    var mapElement = document.getElementById('map');
    var map = new google.maps.Map(mapElement, mapOptions);
    var markers = <?php echo json_encode($markers); ?>; //Passing the PHP values to JS

    //Add marker to map
    for(var i in markers) {
        var marker = markers[i];
        new google.maps.Marker({
            position: new google.maps.LatLng(marker.lat, marker.long),
            map: map,
            title: 'Snazzy!'
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
        <?php
            $lat = ['73.0785729','73.0785729','73.0785729'];
            $long = ['73.0785729', '73.0715769', '73.0785729'];
        ?>

        var lat_array = <?=json_encode($lat)?>;
        var long_array = <?=json_encode($long)?>;

        function init() {
            var mapOptions = {
                zoom: 11,
                center: new google.maps.LatLng(40.6700, -73.9400),
                styles: []
            };
            var mapElement = document.getElementById('map');
            var map = new google.maps.Map(mapElement, mapOptions);

            // assuming that the length of lat_array and long_array are the same
            for(var i = 0; i < lat_array.length; i++){
                var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    position: new google.maps.LatLng(parseFloat(lat_array[i]), parseFloat(long_array[i])),
                    map: map,
                    title: 'Snazzy!'
                });
            }

        }
```